# What is wrong with this deserialization example?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, deserialization

I am trying a simple example for deserialization of an xml file in vb.net 2008, but there must be a simple mistake somewhere.

Error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
```

xml file:

```
<Item>test</Item>
```

vb code:

```
Public Class xmlClass
Public Item As String
End Class
```

...and in the form class:

```
Private Sub Deserialize()
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(xmlClass))
Dim reader As New FileStream("c:\tmp\tmp2.xml", FileMode.Open)
Dim xi As xmlClass
xi = CType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), xmlClass)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<xmlClass>
  <Item>Test</Item>
</xmlClass>
```

You need to put the class element around the field value. I confirmed this works using your above code with VS 2012.

Comment: If you have trouble with this in the future, create an populate an object (xi in the above example) then write it out using Serializer.Serialze(). It will show you the schema you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try deserializing this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Item>test</Item>
```

Comment: I had tried that -- no change. Akton pointed out the problem.